# PDT Device is not getting connected to Windows 10 64Bit PC

Tags: windows-10, windows-ce, motorola-emdk

Windows 10 is not detecting Symbol PDT Device...
And Device is showing Under Uncategorized Devices on Device Manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make Sure, you Correctly attached the device or Driver installed Properly..

Please Refer below link to Install Driver For Windows 10 :

[Click Here for Download Driver](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/evm/windows-ce-device-does-not-connect-with-windows-10-with-creators-upgrade-via-wmdc.html)